# Errors Inserting multiple Data Into Table with Multiple Select and Join Statements

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query that inserts data into table.

```
INSERT INTO linking (user, relaterd, type, changedate, changeuser, createdate, muser, id, common)
   SELECT map.user, mre.uuid,  'BALL',  TIMESTAMP '2019-11-03 00:00:00.000', 'system',  TIMESTAMP '2019-11-03 00:00:00.000',  'system',  uuid_generate_v4(), mre.uuid
   FROM (SELECT user FROM mapuser v JOIN mct m ON v.uid = m.groep) map
   JOIN (SELECT mr.uuid, mr.number FROM mre mr where mr.type = 'KCT') mre ON mre.number = substring(m.groep, 2, length(m.groep));
```

I want the columns "**user**", "**relaterd**" and "**common**" to be filled by the `SELECT-JOIN` statements. The columns "**relaterd**"
and "**common**" have the same values. The other columns are constants.

When I execute this query, I get the **ERROR MESSAGE :: missing FROM-clause entry for table "m".** It's like it wants me to use From clause for the table **"mct"** which I think I don't need it because am  **JOINING** it with **mapuser** table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have table `m` outside `(SELECT user FROM mapuser v JOIN mct m ON v.uid = m.groep)`.

Try to replace m with map:

```
substring(map.groep, 2, length(map.groep))
```

In your query you have only tables `map` in FROM-clause and `mre` joined with it. Other tables' aliases exist only in subqueries.